# How to answer queries of type l,r,k which finds number of elements in an array in range l to r which occurs atleast k times?

Tags: counting, segment-tree

How to compute answer to queries of type l,r,k which finds number of elements in an array which occurs atleast k times in range l to r ? How to use Mo's algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

If you have offline queries, you can use Mo's algorithm.

The following link is quite helpful.[Anudeep's blog - Mo's Algorithm](https://blog.anudeep2011.com/mos-algorithm/)